# How to Use Pandas to Combine Dataframes with Duplicate Index Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine several data frames together, each with one column.  I'm having problems doing so because the index contains duplicate values.  For example:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

names = ["AB","AB","CD","CD"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,1,2], index = names, columns = ["Series1"])
df1.index.rename("Name", inplace=True)

names = ["AB","AB","CD","CD"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,4,3,4], index = names, columns = ["Series2"])
df2.index.rename("Name", inplace=True)

In[2]:
df1
Out[2]: 
      Series1
Name         
AB          1
AB          2
CD          1
CD          2

In[3]:
df2
Out[3]: 
      Series2
Name         
AB          3
AB          4
CD          3
CD          4
```

I want the final Dataframe to look like:

```
      Series1  Series2
Name         
AB          1        3
AB          2        4
CD          1        3
CD          2        4
```

I've tried using concat, append, join, and merge with no luck.
Concat and append give:

```
      Series1  Series2
Name                  
AB        1.0      NaN
AB        2.0      NaN
CD        1.0      NaN
CD        2.0      NaN
AB        NaN      3.0
AB        NaN      4.0
CD        NaN      3.0
CD        NaN      4.0
```

While merge and join give:

```
      Series1  Series2
Name                  
AB          1        3
AB          1        4
AB          2        3
AB          2        4
CD          1        3
CD          1        4
CD          2        3
CD          2        4
```

I've tried several different combinations of parameters for each, but have always gotten the tables above or an error.  What can I use to combine these tables correctly?  It is important for my analysis that the numbers in the series stay associated with the correct name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `concat` works for me:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: I was getting an error earlier today with that using my actual data.  Something about expecting fewer rows than it was given when concatenating.  Seems to be working now, though.  Thanks.